# Logging into harmon.ie - Sorry, something went wrong

Tags: harmon.ie

Does anyone have a solution to the issue of when I log into harmon.ie on outlook either application (latest 2016 O365) or web based outlook, I get the splash screen saying "Sorry, something went wrong".

There is no fault code or anything, so hard to say what exactly the issue is.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have MFA in place?
If yes, forward the instructions in the below link to your Office 365 Global Admin.
https://harmon.ie/kb/harmonie-app-administration-guide#mfa

------ Jean